# linux startup: xinput does not apply settings in script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Ubuntu 15.04 does not have an option for mouse sensitivity, thus the need to set the mouse deceleration property in the xinput,however

```
cybex@cybex-W55xEU:~$ cat mouse_sense.sh

#!/bin/bash
xinput --set-prop 13 294 1.45
```

adding this to ( .bash_profile and gnome startup applications) runs the script, but either does not apply the property or it is overridden by another setting

any help?

**UPDATE**

response to @MariusMatutiae comment,

```
cybex@cybex-W55xEU:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ls -F

10-evdev.conf         11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-wacom.conf
10-quirks.conf        50-synaptics.conf         51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf  50-vmmouse.conf
```

Comment: Don't you have  a mouse file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` where you can put your specifications?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae see update

Comment: Exactly: `50-vmmouse.conf`. From the Xorg manual, http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/vmmouse.4.html: **vmmouse is an XFree86 input driver for mice. The driver supports most available mouse types and interfaces**.

Comment: Can you specify what is property 294?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae it is the "Constant Deceleration" property, check update please, for possible fix

Comment: @MariusMatutiae couldn't have done it without your help :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Possible Solution**

After some research,

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

run

```
ls -F
```

produces result:

```
cybex@cybex-W55xEU:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ls -F

10-evdev.conf         11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-wacom.conf
10-quirks.conf        50-synaptics.conf         51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf  50-vmmouse.conf
```

adding the mouse sensitivity adjustment settings:
create a new file with

```
nano 50-mouse-acceleration.conf
```

enter the following into the file

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "1.45"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "1.45"
EndSection
```

output of the file (cat file) shows

```
cybex@cybex-W55xEU:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ cat 50-mouse-acceleration.conf 
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "1.45"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "1.45"
EndSection
```

this should automatically adjust you mouse speed, change the value of "1.45" (I changed both accordingly), lower - increase speed, higher - decrease speed.